# Locked out of tablet!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

My niece downloaded an application and she did a pattern, but did not pay attention, and now shes locked out of her device, it will not even turn off can u help please!!

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need more information... Is it an App locker? A custom lockscreen? A gallery locker? What is the name of the app? What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the power button, sometimes it takes 10 seconds but it will force shutdown eventually. After that, find what key combo boots it up in recovery mode, and find Wipe data or Factory reset and select it. This will wipe all your data but since you cant get to it anyway it doesnt matter. This will also clear any patterns you have set earlier.